# how to add the support library dependency by using Ant?

Tags: java, android, gradle, ant, dependencies

I use Microsoft VC++ 2010 Express, Ant 1.10.1 , vs-android, android SDK/NDK to build our android apk. It works very well.
Since I want to use android.support.design.widget.NavigationView, so I use below layout xml:

```
<com.nchsoftware.library.LJAbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_window"
/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When build, I met below error:

> 1>       [aapt] Generating resource IDs... 1>       [aapt]
>   C:\SourceCode\llib\android\res\layout\activity_main.xml:15: error: No
>   resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package '

I found that adding `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'` dependencies in `build.gradle` file can resolve this problem if using `Gradle`.

But we don't use `Gradle`, instead we use `Ant`. Do you know how to add this in `Ant`? Thank you!

Comment: Are you referring ivy dependency management thing? You probably just add a new extra task to do it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650590/how-to-add-dependency-to-ant-project

Comment: Yes, I refer to ivy, since it is a big topic, so I still don't know how to do. By default, new Android Studio projects declare JCenter as the repository location in the project's top-level build.gradle file. I don't know how to refer this repository in ivy. I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650590/how-to-add-dependency-to-ant-project . Yes, they are related question. I'll also ask a question base on it.

Comment: also what SDK version does you use? 25.+? the dependency you referred seems 26.+?

Comment: I use SDK API 26. The dependency refer 26.+, I think this is the support library version, not the SDK API version.