# Java 8 to 11 Upgrade Error- Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy. Unable to run project despite the dependency update

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, ant, java-11

I am trying to upgrade my java application from Java 7 to Java 11 version. My local is setup with jdk11 and Java_Home is updated as well. Running the app in Intellij 2023.1 IDE which is the latest version.

When running the local application which is pointing to Jdk11 facing Error: '*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy*'.
Changes made to my local are the jdk previously was pointing to java 8, now it is pointing to java 11.

I have read previous posts on the same error and everyone suggested for a downgrade of the jdk from 11 to 8. But in my case I have to upgrade the application to Java 11 and the the project is on Ant build.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if any additional information is required.

I have tried upgrading the libraries and still the same issue is persist.

Comment: The `javax.annotation` package is no longer included in Java, you need to add the appropriate dependency.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Mine is a ant project. Any suggestion on the replacement for javax.annotation package?

Comment: Try to try to download the JAR from [Maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api) and add the [dependency to ant project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650590/how-to-add-dependency-to-ant-project)

Comment: Also, make sure you're using an Ant version which is compatible with Java 11.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Added latest jar and upgraded ant version. Solution worked. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @MiguelMonteiro Added latest jar and upgraded ant version. Solution worked. Appreciate your help!